# Issue with Postback and Custom Validators in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, postback, customvalidator

I need some help on an issue, related with asp.net validators and postback.

The issue is that I have a page say 'p1' and it has a master page 'm1'. In addition to these I also have a usercontrol 'u1'.

Now, the issue is that on master page 'm1', I have a button that initiates a postback. And on my usercontrol 'u1', I have some fields which I need to check/validate and stop the postback if the fields are invalid.

I have tried using customvalidators and forcefully calling Page.Validate() method. But by doing this, I can see the page.IsValid property is false but sill the postback happens. I have even tried to write a return statement if the control fields are invalid but it doesn't helps..

Please note that I do not want to make any changes in the masterpage as this may have high impact on the other pages.

Answer (score 0):

If clicking a button causes postbacks even when the page is invalid (as in your case it is proven with Page.IsValid property is False), then this means the button isn't configured to check for validations on the client side.

Solution 1:
You need to intialize the "CausesValidation" Property of the Button with the value True"

However, this requires changing the markup of the "Button" on the markup. And this isn't something you wish to perform.

Solution 2:
You can from within your page, access the Button of the Master page from within the Load Event and Initialize the CausesValidation property of the button to True.
Have a look at the following link to find the button from within the master page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx